# How to identify message content and return True or False

Tags: powershell

I was trying to figure out a way where PS will read each file in the folder. If it is able to read those file, PS should mark it as True along with file extension name. But if PS is not able to open/read the file, it should mark it as False along with the file extension name.

Below is the first command I tried:

```
(get-content 'c:\desktop\parent_folder\hideme1.txt' -Raw) -match "\r\n$"
```

The response I got is False even though it is a text file

When I tried the below command(assuming it will check all the file type), I am getting different response.

```
(get-content 'c:\desktop\parent_folder\*.*' -Raw) -match "\r\n$"
```

The response I got for the 2nd command is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I know both the commands are not even getting me to the close result, Kindly educate me how to solve it step by step.

Comment: Are you looking for just _a_ newline or a really just for one _at the end of the file_ as your use of `$` suggests?

Comment: Also note that `Get-Content` will still _read_ a non-text file - it'll just misinterpret it _as text_ - unless you use `-Encoding Byte` (Windows PowerShell) `-AsByteStream` (PowerShell (Core) 7+).

Comment: As for the difference in `-match` behavior: With a _collection_ (such as an array) as the LHS, PowerShell comparison operators such as `-eq` act as _filters_ and return an _array of matching items_ rather than a Boolean.
The return array is always of type `[object[]]`, i.e. a regular PowerShell array, irrespective of the specific LHS collection type - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).

Comment: Also note that text files may have Unix-style newlines, which are a single `\n` (LF) characters, unlike the Windows-style `\r\n` (CRLF) sequences. To match both with a regex, use `\r?\n`

Comment: @mklement0

1. I have many files within a folder, it should read all the files(whichever it can like txt, docx, csv) and report it as TRUE. If it is not able to open a file, it should mark it as False.

2. As a beginner, I just tried with txt file in the sample code. But it did not work.

Comment: Also please suggest when to use 1. Raw 2.match  3."\r\n$

Comment: If you just want to know if `Get-Content` reports an _error_ when trying to open a file (because the path doesn't exist or you lack permissions, ...), go with @RetiredGeek's answer. `-Raw` loads a file _in full_, as a single, (typically) multi-line string; assuming the file fits into memory (which is likely in the case of text files), it is by far the fastest way to read a file in PowerShell - though you may have to do splitting into individual lines yourself, if needed. `-match '\r\n$'` looks for a CRLF newline at the end of the input string - not sure how that relates to your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning,

What you need if you are just trying to see if the file is readable is a Try/Catch block as follows:

```
#*** Get list of files ***
$Files = (Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\Test" -File).FullName 
#*** Next line for testing only ***
$Files += "G:\Test\Forced Missing File.txt"

#*** Iterate through file list ***
  ForEach ($File in $Files) {

#*** Attempt to open file and upon error cause a STOP Error Action***
     Try   { $Null = Get-Content "$File" -Raw -EA Stop }

#*** If STOP action print message ***
    Catch { "Can't Read File: $File"                 }

} #End ForEach
```

You'll notice I added a bogus file name to the list for testing and the results look like this:

```
Can't Read File: G:\Test\Forced Missing File.txt
```

You can of course change the code so the Try block returns True and the Catch block returns False per your needs.

HTH